# lock scroll bar in certain section

Tags: javascript

```
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

i found this code online , which will lock your scroll bar in all browser , i only want certain scroll bar to be lock , but this code lock all scroll bar.
i only want to lock the background scroll bar and i dont wanted to use css.

but as you see in demo both scroll wont move.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/DHz77/549/)

Comment: I do not see any scrollbar being blocked. What you do is you disable teh mousewheel.

Comment: Can't you just add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS of the element that you don't want to scroll?

Comment: cause it remove the scroll bar if i use the css , haha i want the scroll bar to stay and lock it.

Comment: Just to fool the user and affect their user experience? "Ha ha, here is this control that you cannot use!"

Comment: haha i know is too much for just a small thing, but will user think it was weird if i remove it? if use css it will be simple alot.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript Solution

If you want really to use Javascript for this and to lock the scroll wheel (which is what you are doing) only when a user is on a specific `div` or element you can do that by adding an on hover listener to these elements:

```
$('#lock').hover(function() {
     disableScroll();
}, function() {
     enableScroll();
});
```

**Check my jsFiddle for a working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DHz77/553/

---

### CSS Solution

If you want to disable the scrollbars and scrolling on a specific div using css rules, use:

```
#lock { /* or .classname */
    height: 100%; /* or some px */
    overflow-y:hidden; 
}
```

In your case it was actually the body that was scrolling, so I had to adapt the css of the body as well:

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DHz77/559/